# Lim sup and liminf with Fatou's lemma

Tags: measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf

I have some trouble understanding the following homework.

With measure space $(\mathbb{N},\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}),\mu)$ where $\mu$ is the counting measure, we have $(f_n)_{n\geq1},(g_n)_{n\geq1} \in \mathcal{M}^+$ as

$f_n=\mathbb{1}_{\{n\}}$ and $g_n=
\begin{cases}
\mathbb{1}_{\{1\}} \text{ if n is odd}\\
\mathbb{1}_{\{2\}} \text{ if n is even}
\end{cases}
$

(i)

Find $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n, \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} g_n$

(ii)

Show that:

$\int_\mathbb{N} \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n d\mu < \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_\mathbb{N} f_n d\mu$

and

$\int_\mathbb{N} \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} g_n d\mu > \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_\mathbb{N} g_n d\mu$

I have:

$\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n=0, \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} g_n=0$

This satisfies the first inequality in (2) as the integral is always 1 so 0<1. However the same approach goes complete wrong in the second inequality where I have 0>2 which is absurd.

Can anyone see what is wrong? I think maybe I am misunderstanding the limsup or liminf concepts :( I am assuming limsup and liminf are pointwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made two mistakes in dealing with $g_n.$

For the first, note that $$g_n(1) = \begin{cases}1 & \text{ if } n \text{ is odd} \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$
so that $$\left(\limsup g_n\right)(1) = 1$$

Doing the same [point-wise] analysis with $g_n(2),$ we see that $(\limsup g_n)(2) = 1$ and it will be zero for all other inputs.  That is, $\limsup g_n = 1_{\{1,2\}}.$  Use this to evaluate $\int_\mathbb{N} \limsup g_n\,d\mu.$

For the second, you should re-visit $\int_\mathbb{N} g_n\,d\mu.$  It's never going to be equal to $2.$

Comment: Ok, as I understand then $\lim_\mathbb{N} \limsup g_n d\mu=2 > 1=\limsup \int_\mathbb{N} g_n d\mu$. But isn't x chosen first and then limsup is taken afterwards, so it becoms pointwise?

Comment: Yes.  At which point do you believe we've done it any other way?